# How can we UnionAll 2 tables that have different number of columns using Dataframes (created by structtype method) in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, hbase, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 dataframes that are created using `StructType` method in Spark.
They both have unequal number of columns.
Need to unionall them. Kindly assist.

Answer (score 0):

> Its NOT Possible with Spark Dataframes un less you add dummy columns
>
> DataFrame UninonAll is just like your SQL union all in which you need
>   to have  same number of columns and same datatypes...

[***union all***](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#unionAll(org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame)) basic requirement is types, order should be same in either RDBMS sql or DataFrames.

***which means that they return the same number of columns and the corresponding columns have compatible data types***

So you can create dummy columns of the same name/type to align with union requirements.

> unionAll public DataFrame unionAll(DataFrame other)
>
> Returns a new DataFrame containing union of rows in this frame and
>   another frame. This is equivalent to UNION ALL in SQL.
>
> Parameters:
>
> other - (undocumented)
>
> Returns:
>
> (undocumented)
>
> Since:
>
> 1.3.0

---

SQL Examples :

#### CASE 1:

** Possible : where a(int datatype),b(int datatype),c(int datatype) &  x(int datatype), y(int datatype),z(int datatype) are same data type **

```
select a, b, c from table1 
unionall
select x,y,z from table2
```

#### CASE 2:

** NOT Possible : where a(int type),b(int type),c(int type) &  p(int type),q(int type),r(int type), x(String type), y(int type),z(String type)  **

```
select a, b, c from table1 
 unionall
select p, q,r, x,y,z from table2
```

#### CASE 3:

**To make it possible you add dummy columns to table 1
 x(String type), y(int type),z(String type)**

#### In this case I added dummy columns  "dasarathy" as x, 2 as y, "dr" as z

```
 select a, b, c, "dasarathy" as x, 2 as y, "dr" as z from table1 
     unionall
    select p, q,r, x,y,z from table2
```

Same is true in case of dataframes as well.

#### Conclusion :  If its absolutely needed, you can add dummy columns (using `withColumn`) to dataframe to make dataframe1 `unionall` dataframe2

Comment: was my answer useful?

Comment: No. The answer is more generic.

Comment: I havent seen your message since you have not added @myname so pls do it hence forth. I added sql examples for your understanding, which are similar in Dataframes as well. Hope you understood now.

Comment: also if you need more examples you need to comment & converse. that's good habit. so that users will respond with more information. if you keep quiet users wont get motivation to answer your questions. Also Feel free to ask questions if you have any.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Ram